# WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN --Update table - id field and insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge, sql-server-2008-r2

I doubt this can be done, thought I would ask the experts.

I have two large tables and have a need to merge them (excluding a non identity integer key field). All PK's are maintained in a `NextId` table here.

So, my question is, if I have an insert during `MERGE` - is there a way to grab the `NextId` for this table and update this table for each insert?

Comment: You can't modify NextID table data inside a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible but you might be able to generate the IDs beforehand. Example:

1. Generate all IDs and store them in a table variable. Join that table variable in the `MERGE` statement.
2. If the IDs are contiguous you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (something) + startingID` to generate them as part of the `MERGE`.